# How to make the hyphen show right in the middle of the paragraph title and its content

Tags: formatting

I am writing paragraphs that seldom require titles. I'd like the paragraph name to be separated from the actual content with a symbol. It can be an hyphen or whatever. My issue is if I type:

```
\paragraph*{My great title -} My fantastic content goes here.
```

there is way too much space between the hyphen and the content and similarly if I type:

```
\paragraph*{My great title} - My fantastic content goes here.
```

Is there a way to let the hyphen to nicely plump in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) document class, `\paragraph` leaves a gap of `1em` in the prevailing font (`\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries`). So, using

```
\paragraph*{My great title}{\bfseries\hspace{-1em}}~-~My fantastic content goes here.
```

would yield equivalent spacing of a non-breaking space around the hyphen `-`. Of course, you could replace that with whatever length you're interested in. Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\parhyphen}[1][1em]{% Symmetric \paragraph hyphen
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\hspace*{-1em}}\hspace*{#1}-\hspace*{#1}\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\paragraph*{My great title} - My fantastic content goes here.

\paragraph*{My great title -} My fantastic content goes here.

\paragraph*{My great title}\parhyphen[2em]My fantastic content goes here.

\paragraph*{My great title}\parhyphen[30pt]My fantastic content goes here.
\end{document}
```

`\parhyphen[<len>]` inserts a paragraph hyphen of length `<len>` (defaults to `1em` in `\normalfont`).

---

It would be possible to redefine `\paragraph` and insert this dash in a manual fashion using, for example:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {0pt}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

in your document preamble. Then you could use

```
\paragraph*{My great title} \mbox{} - My fantastic content goes here.
```

Comment: I am a pretty basic LaTeX user, hope you don't mind me asking is there a way to avoid repeating all this markup, maybe override the `\paragraph{}` command?

Comment: @haunted85: This could be done using a package like [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). Do *all* of your `\paragraph`s have this dash?